# How to save thumbnail for files saved using image.save in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, caching

I'm saving images:

```
myImage.Save(strFilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It's working great. But when I go into the folder, there are lots of files and so it takes a while for Windows to display the extra large thumbnail for the first time. Is there a way I can use an option to just have Windows automatically add the image to the cache when it's saving it (or right after)? I'm fine with using the default cache.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this resolved the issue (posted by someone but they since removed their answer), but I'm not positive... 

myImage.GetThumbnailImage(120, 120, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);